# Visual Studio - Using different versions for the same project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I recently started a new job, and got a machine with Visual Studio 2013 Proffesional installed. This would be great, except the colleague that I'm working with is using Visual Studio 2010. As far as I know, there is no way to work on the same project (or solution), without having quite a lot of issues, is this correct?

And if so, is it still possible to download Visual Studio 2010 (from a reliable source)? I cannot seem to find it anywhere in my MSDN subscriber downloads. All I can find is a stuff like service packs, tools, etc. Did they terminate the support of it?

Answer (score 0):

You work on visual studio 2013 but there are option to select which version of visual studio you want select 2010 and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open Visual Studio 2013 solutions in 2010, if you install [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691). There is a possibility that some project types won't be supported, but the solution should open.

Comment: I can easily open them, and I can also build them. Problem is that it wants to change it to a VS2013 project when I'm building it. After that, my colleague cannot use it again. I'm gonna try to install VS2010 SP1 and see if I can build it as a 2010 project after that. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is changing, the *solution* file (.sln) or the project? If it's the solution, VS2010 with SP1 *should* be able to open it, even if it's changed to 2013. If it's a project (.csproj), well... what kind of project is it?

Comment: I'm still new to Visual Studio, but it seems to be a .vcxproj file. Last time I opened it, and made a build, it made some changes to the project file, which caused my colleague a lot of trouble when he tried to build the next time. I am not sure if he has SP1 installed.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, those are C++ projects and they are quite picky about the compiler version... You could work around that by twiddling the values inside the `.vcxproj`, but it might be just easier to install VS2010 as well (it should be on MSDN!).

Comment: I will see if I can find VS2010. Thanks for your suggestions.